# Capistrano using sudo even with "set :use_sudo, false"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, sudo, rvm-capistrano

I do not wish to use sudo for any of my remotely executed commands via Capistrano. Specifically, when I run `cap deploy:setup`, I'm asked for my sudo password during the first `mkdir` command. I added `set :use_sudo, false` to my deploy.rb file, but this did not make a difference.

I started with a fairly complete deploy.rb file, but whittled it down once I started having issues. Here is my minimal version that still shows `use_sudo` not being respected:

```
# App Definitions

set :domain, '[server-ip]'
role :app, domain
role :web, domain
role :db, domain, :primary => true

set :user, "my_app"
set :use_sudo, false

task :sudo_test do
  run "#{try_sudo} whoami"
end
```

running `cap sudo_test` results in me being prompted for my sudo password.  What am I missing here (besides the hair I've already pulled out)?

**Google Findings**

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/capistrano/QNYnvW8obrg

A thread with someone having a similar issue. No conclusion/resolution noted in the thread.

Comment: what is that `#{try_sudo}` bit? what if you take it out?

Comment: `#{try_sudo}` should _sudoize_ the command if `:use_sudo` is set to `false`. I include it in `sudo_test` because the capistrano rails tasks likely use it as well, and is likely where the problem stems from.

Comment: We use 'sudo -i <cmd>' in our deploy.rb file.

Comment: and this too: sudo 'aptitude install -y rsync'

Comment: As mentioned above, the initial reason for the post is that `cap deploy:setup` is trying to use sudo when I don't want it to. `cap deploy:setup` is a pre-baked recipe; I'm not looking to modify it. Rather, I need to determine why the option `:use_sudo` isn't working.

Comment: Are you sure it's prompting for your sudo password rather than your SSH password? I tried your setup and it's prompting for my SSH password.

Comment: @JeroenRosenberg You are seeing that because you haven't set up ssh key authentication. Mine is related to `sudo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, it is not possible to disable sudo functionality with certain capistrano tasks. The assumption is that the unprivileged user on the server should not be able to carry out certain tasks.

The command in question is `mkdir`. I'd argue that an unprivileged user should be able to run this command if the parent folder is one that they have permission to do so for. I'd also argue that the user may in fact be a privileged user, such as root. Best practice? Not necessarily. Within the realm of reason for certain deployments, yes.

Here is the link to the response to my original question:

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/211#issuecomment-7667467

Comment: :use_sudo, false worked for me with mkdir (using deploy:setup)

Answer (score 12):

For anyone else who runs into this issue and is a fool like me. Make sure you arn't quoting false. I had:

```
set :use_sudo, "false"
```

and when I switched it to

```
set :use_sudo, false
```

most things started working the way I expected. As YWCA Hello points out there are still commands that ignore the use_sudo setting. However, don't forget to set it correctly.

Comment: As an explanation (without reading the relevant part of the capistrano code): "false" is a true-ish value in ruby. Only nil and false are false-ish. Any other value, incl. 0, "", [], are considered true.
So setting :use_sudo to "false" is the same as setting :use_sudo to true.